# Flutter - Use both GlobalKey and ValueKey for a custom widget

Tags: flutter

I have a custom widget class which I need to render it into a bitmap icon using `BitmapDescriptor`, so I need to define it's `GlobalKey`.

```
GlobalKey<TheWidgetState> globalkey = GlobalKey<TheWidgetState>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {... TheWidget(globalkey) ...}

...
//Somewhere. Has nothing to do with the issue
BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes((await (await (globalkey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary).toImage()).toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png))!.buffer.asUint8List());
...
```

Before doing that, I also need to update the state of the widget before render it like in above code, without changing it's position on the tree. So I also need to define it's `ValueKey` to do that.

I'm still confused about the purpose of every other key types in Flutter. But as for now I need both the purpose of `GlobalKey` and `ValueKey` for my widget. Since both need to be defined with variable name `key`, I have neither an idea on how to set the widget with both keys nor an answer which key serve both purposes that I need.

Greatly appreciate the help.